# ContactStore ContactChanged event is not firing when Modifying Contacts

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10-universal

Modified case is never called when modifying the contact or adding a phone number

```
 _contactStore.ContactChanged += _contactStore_ContactChanged;


private void _contactStore_ContactChanged(ContactStore sender, ContactChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            var defferal = args.GetDeferral();

            ContactChangeReader reader = sender.ChangeTracker.GetChangeReader();
            IReadOnlyList<ContactChange> changes = reader.ReadBatchAsync().AsTask().Result;

            while (changes.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (ContactChange change in changes)
                {
                    switch (change.ChangeType)
                    {
                        case ContactChangeType.Modified: SomeLogic();
                          break;
                    }
                }
               changes = reader.ReadBatchAsync().AsTask().Result;
            }
            reader.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: Does the following answer work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that the [`ContactStoreAccessType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactStoreAccessType) type is incorrect. Please try use `AllContactsReadWrite` enumeration type.

```
ContactStore store = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync(ContactStoreAccessType.AllContactsReadWrite);
store.ContactChanged += Store_ContactChanged;

private void Store_ContactChanged(ContactStore sender, ContactChangedEventArgs args)
{

}
```